# Source of Debian packages older than 2005

Tags: debian, source, snapshot

I want to download packages for years 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003 and 2004 but Debian snapshots are maintained from March 2005 only. How can I get the source of packages before 2005?

Comment: What packages precisely?

Comment: there are almost 10 packages i am looking for.. linux, chrominum/browser, icedove, wireshark, xulrunner, openjdk,php,imagemagick, mysql.

Comment: There's a completely different reason for the unavailability of Chromium from 2004.  (-:

Comment: what's the reason? and what about other packages? Is there any link from where i can download the source of all these for previous years?

Comment: @Hazel  the first release of Chromium came out in 2008.

Answer (score 1):

You can find old releases of Debian [here](http://archive.debian.org/debian/dists/). You won't find all the snapshots of packages, only the versions that were released.

Answer (score 0):

You can find cd images at archive.org.
https://archive.org/search.php?query=creator%3A%22Debian+Project%22

Comment: I am not looking for debain image. I am looking for packages. After year 2005 , i can get them from snapshots maintained by debian.. but before 2005 i dont know how to get them. there are almost 10 packages i am looking for.. linux, chrominum/browser, icedove, wireshark, xulrunner, openjdk,php,imagemagick, mysql

Comment: CD images contain all binary and source packages. (1st release of chromium was in 2008)